# access main window from dialog in qt

Tags: c++, qt

in the main window their is lineEdit_1 and in the dialog their is lineEdit_2. once a button is clicked the dialog window will open. now I need the lineEdit_2 to get the value of lineEdit_1 in the main window.

(the main window class is `MainWindow` and dialog window class is `dialog` )

I tried to do it like this, but it gives a error `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'MainWindow' with no type`

dialog.h

```
MainWindow *main; //declair a pointer to the main window
```

dialog.cpp

```
lineEdit_2->setText(main->lineEdit_1->text());
```

whats the mistake here.

I would be very thankful in any advice. thank you.

Comment: Have you perhaps forgotten to include the header file for your MainWindow class? Also you need to pass the pointer of your main window to the dialog somehow, either in the constructor or in a function.

Comment: @DanielHedberg I have already added `mainwindow.h` in the `dialog.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

```
      void dialog::lineText(QString text){

       lineEdit_text = text;  //let lineEdit_text be a QString member in your 
                              //dialog class. Pass the text before calling
                              //setVisible() in the client code
     }
```